# C# Credential Provider UpdateRemoteCredential not firing while connecting with RDP

Tags: c#, winapi, credential-providers, winlogon

I developed a custom credential provider by using C# and it works both unlock and logon scenario locally. When its CREDUI scenario, i can logon or unlock remote computer with my local Credential provider.

My filter is registered in regedit. Same DLL but different classes.

1. What I cannot to do is, catch logon or unlock scenario on remote computer with my custom  credential provider. I implemented filter interface. UpdateRemoteCredential not working. What could i missing? How can I say "use this credential provider while logging in" in server machine. Thanks.

Comment: your credential provider must be on target comp, not on comp from where rdp connect

Comment: My credential provider (same provider) is installed on the remote machine. But i always need to logon twice because NLA is enabled. I want to enter my credentials in client machine CREDUI then catch credentials on remote machine and go on my operation.

Comment: if you correct register filter on target comp, UpdateRemoteCredential will be called (if client pass some credentials). NLA not affect cred providers. not need logon twice

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"? Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Provider Filters and Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Authentication\Credential Providers these keys right?

Comment: yes, under filters. when rdp logon atemp, UpdateRemoteCredential must be called

Comment: My filter and CP guids are different. This is not a problem right?

Comment: it always must be different. this is not problem. this is must. when logon attemp and client pass some credentials, both Filter and UpdateRemoteCredential must be called on registered filter. if unlock - no any data, only Filter will be called

Comment: Filter is called but not filtering other CP's (when i debug, breakpoint hits and filter code runs. But not disabling other CP's). UpdateRemoteCredential is not firing at all.

Comment: possible client not pass any credentials to remote side in this case

Comment: Yes, i can share Filter implementation code if you need.

Comment: here need look under debugger on target system, not on your code

Comment: if you do usual rdp login from mstsc (without custom cred providers on client), are UpdateRemoteCredential called in this case ?

Comment: Trying now. I will inform. Thanks.

Comment: No not firing. Will updateRemoteCredential fire in target machine or client machine?

Comment: if your Filter is called, so cred provider correct registered and loaded. of course updateRemoteCredential must be called on rdp target

Comment: if exist credential system call your implementation of UpdateRemoteCredential (if system call Filter).

Comment: UpdateRemoteCredential is called when i logon from a system CP. I unregistered / registered again. Now its working but not logging me in. Asks me credentials twice.

Comment: Also Server-side UpdateRemoteCredential is called when i logon with my CP in client side.

Comment: so about you ask ?

Comment: Finally i made it work correctly. UpdateRemoteCredential -> SetSerialization works. My custom provider works well on remote connections too.

Comment: this is strange, because your implementation of UpdateRemoteCredential is wrong. you need set `Statics.CredentialProviderUID` in `pcpcsOut` credentials, not in `pcpcsIn`. unclear what is `new` here mean, memory must be allocated by `CoTaskMemAlloc`. probably need first check `pcpcsIn` before try modify it, but not unconditional allocate `pcpcsOut`. however `c#` very hard understand.

Comment: I corrected it. Now it covers all the scenarios both interactive and remote. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I did it and covered all scenarios both interactive and remote logon. Firstly, UpdateRemoteCredential is firing on target system (i didn't know that). Credential Filter must be installed correctly on target machine. After UpdateRemoteCredential fires, I needed to hold serialized credentials in SetSerialization method (ICredentialProvider implementation). After that, in ICredentialProviderCredential2 implementation, SetSelected method fires. In SetSelected method, I set pbAutoLogon to 1 (because i have credentials). After that, GetSerialization method is fired and its done.

Method order in RDP connections;

- UpdateRemoteCredential (get serialized credentials)
- SetSerialization (hold serialized credentials in implementation)
- SetSelected (set auto logon property to 1)
- GetSerialization (give serialized credentials to system)

Comment: more correct in `GetCredentialCount` set `pbAutoLogonWithDefault` to `true` and return `pdwDefault`